# Upper of lower side for chi square test of variances

Tags: variance, chi-squared-test

[image]

I'm reading the introductory statistics and get stuck at chi square test for variances. Like the image shown below, the alternative hypothesis is that

> $σ^2 < 7.2^2$

. But if we plug this inequality into the formula for the calculation of chi square value $(n-1)*S^2/σ^2$ (S is the sample standard deviation), the result is supposed to be $χ^2 > (n-1)*S^2/7.2^2 = 5.67$, which suggests that this is a upper sided test. However, the truth is that this is a lower sided test. Is there anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the inequality in your last expression? 5.67, the test statistic, is the same for any test. The sidedness affects the p value or inference.

Comment: @AdamO Just as the image shown, the formula is $χ^2 = (n-1)S^2/sigma^2$. If I plug $sigma^2 < 7.2^2$ into it, I can get the inequality.

Comment: The shaded area of the chisquare curve represents the critical area for the test. It is left tailed as you say. The test statistic is in the critical region. Are you having  trouble finding the 13.85 critical value?

Comment: 5.67 is the correct statistic. It suggests the test is statistically significant.

Comment: @AdamO No, I have no trouble finding the correct statistic, but transforming it to p-value. The image shows that for an alternative hypothesis $\sigma^2 < 7.2^2$, the p-value should be obtained by a lower tail area. However, I'm thinking that as the $\sigma^2$ is at the denominator, this question should be solved with a upper tail test.

Comment: Where did you come up with "$\gt$" after "the result is supposed to be"?

Comment: @whuber Because the $X^2$ value is calculated based on formula $xxxx/\sigma^2$, isn't it? So if I want to test the alternative hypothesis, which is $\sigma < 7.2$, shouldn't I get a $X^2$ value ">" than the statistic with the formula?

Comment: But there's no p value. If you want it, find the left tailed area for 5.67 on the 24 df chi square df. Upper tail test makes no sense. If the true var was bigger than 7.2, the test statistic is big, consistent with the null hypothesis.

Comment: The value of the chi-squared statistic is calculated as shown in the formulas you cite.  The issue concerns whether you will compute the area to the left of its value or to the right for the associated chi-squared distribution.  The text you cite clearly explains at the outset that the left area is the desired one.  Where is the problem?

Comment: @whuber That's the problem. Is there any way that I can get a strict proof that "less" is a "left-tailed" test for chi square distribution?

Comment: Yes: look at the picture.  Label its left side and right side.  Write down the side corresponding to the shaded area.  *QED*.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I think your problem is that you wonder why for a given alpha like 0.05, your test statistic is on the right side and 1-alpha on the left side. because in chi square distribution area you have under the curve is being computed from right not left(unlike t-test for example)